# Do we always need "Consumer Key" for every client for Connected App?

Tags: rest-api, salesforce1-app, appexchange, connected-apps, key

I am trying to import datas to multiple SF clients (all of them are different companies). As soon as I saw on the internet, I can see that client needs to implement a connected app in order to enable me to connect their salesforce. The question I am asking right now can I implement a Connected Application and put it to AppExchange so that whenever it is Consumer Keys every time for every user ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You should have just one connected app, and therefore one client ID. When a user connects to your app for the first time, it will automatically place a connected app setting in their org for your client ID. This allows administrators to control the permissions for your app, see how many users are using the app, and when the last usage of your app was, and even block or revoke access to your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I am not misunderstood, one can install my APP for exchange store, so that once he give me the authentication, I will be able to send the data ? 

Myapp --> Enterprise1 and at the same time 
Myapp --> Enterprise2   ??

Comment: That's correct. A consumer ID (or client ID) identifies your app uniquely, not the organization you're connecting to.